# Spring/Grails; How exactly are property editors used?

Tags: spring, grails, propertyeditor

In the articles I have seen, the authors only seem so discuss creating custom property editors and registering them. How do I actually use them? Are they only automatically used during data-binding?

Answer (score 1):

Property editors are used automatically during databinding, but [databinding was radically changed in Grails 2.3](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.0/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew23), and implementing property editors is no longer the recommended way to customize databinding.

Comment: Hi Donal, what I'm interested in is the idea of Property Editors. I mean their motivation and in what way they are used other than data binding. Everything in spring seems not well explained.